# Fill View with UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to fill my view but it'll not reduce its quality like aspectfill, so can someone tell me that how to achieve UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit property flavor and my view should be fill??
If i'll just use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit property so what'll be image resolution to fillup the view???

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` fits the image into the view, so if the image has a different aspect ratio than the view, there will be blank spaces left on the top and bottom or left and right of the image.

`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` makes the image fill the view, so extra width or height (not both) will be cropped off.

None of these modes reduce the quality of the image. If your image has a small resolution, it will be stretched to fit the view. If your image has a larger resolution, it will be shrunk to fit the view.

Try using `UIViewContentModeCenter`. It will not resize the image, but center it in the view at original resolution.